# Rails autoload don't load module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app, I have a custom directory in `app/entities/keycard_generator/`

I have a data_source.rb (a module) and register_keycard.rb (a class)

```
module DataSource
  ...
end

class RegisterKeycard
  include DataSource
...
end
```

I have added this line in my application.rb, to autoload the path.

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('app/entities/keycard_generator/**/*.rb')].each(&method(:require))
```

But I get this errors (cannot run rails) :

```
uninitialized constant RegisterKeycard::DataSource (NameError)
```

### Edit

I think that the issue is only with modules

Comment: Your problem is with naming and file location. Please edit your question to include the location of your `DataSource` and `RegisterKeycard` files.

Comment: there are both in app/entities/keycard_generator/ folder @jvillian

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have:

```
app/entities/keycard_generator/data_source.rb
```

Then the content of that file, by convention, should be:

```
module KeycardGenerator
  module DataSource
    ...
  end
end
```

Because rails essentially ignores the directory name under `app` (here, `entities`) in terms of naming:

```
app/entities/keycard_generator/data_source.rb
    ^^^^^^^^
```

But expects the directory name under the directory under app (here, `keycard_generator`) to be a module name:

```
app/entities/keycard_generator/data_source.rb
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And given that you have:

```
app/entities/keycard_generator/register_keycard.rb
```

Then the content of that file, by convention, should be:

```
module KeycardGenerator
  class RegisterKeycard 
    include DataSource
  end
end
```

When following the convention, you do not need:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('app/entities/keycard_generator/**/*.rb')].each(&method(:require))
```

Personally, I like to append the type (here, indicated by `entities`) to the files and modules/classes, like:

```
app/entities/keycard_generator/data_source_entity.rb
module KeycardGenerator
  module DataSourceEntity
    ...
  end
end
```

Which is how rails often (e.g., with `controller`) but not always (e.g., with `model`) does it.

In which case you would also do:

```
app/entities/keycard_generator/register_keycard_entity.rb
module KeycardGenerator
  class RegisterKeycardEntity
    include DataSourceEntity
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is it always mandatory to use that convention ? Is there a way to avoid the nested "module > module > module" if there is a deep folder hierarchy ?

Comment: If you want rails' autoload to work correctly and you want to avoid `uninitialized constant` errors, then you are well advised to follow the convention. It is not, however, entirely required. You might want to take a look at [this article](https://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/) or google around as I am confident there are many others.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the included module as global by prefixing the name with `::`

```
class RegisterKeycard
  include ::DataSource
...
end
```